# Any browser plugins for customizing web pages intelligently?

Tags: browser, web

I generally use firebug to remove unwanted divs and tags and resize stuff on the web-page .. frequently for gaming sites like chessbomb. But this is tedious, and every time tab reloads, i would have to do it all over again.

So is there any plugin which would remember the setting for particular site and apply it on the load itself. For starters i just need something to remove div tags based on names. If it can resize too then thats all the more useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Adblock Plus with some CSS selector usage to do this.  Look at the doc related to this [here](http://adblockplus.org/en/filters).

For example, you could probably use something like

```
domain.com##div.class
```

to hide those divs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a use case for the [greasemonkey firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/). You'll need to know a little javascript, but if you're doing these sorts of things in Firebug, I would assume you won't find greasemonkey too dofficult.

Have a look at http://www.greasespot.net/ and http://userscripts.org/ and you may even find someone has already written the script you're after.

To quote [wikipedia on Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey):

> Greasemonkey is a Mozilla Firefox extension that allows users to install scripts that make on-the-fly changes to HTML web page content on the DOMContentLoaded event, which happens immediately after it is loaded in the browser (also known as augmented browsing).
>
> As Greasemonkey scripts are persistent, the changes made to the web pages are executed every time the page is opened, making them effectively permanent for the user running the script.